# When to release UIButton in UITableView cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I am trying to add a button to a cell in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. That works but  I seem to be adding a button every time the cell is updated (discovered this because I have updated the wrong screen position and I have 2 buttons that both work and can be clicked).

When is the correct time to allocate and release a `UIButton` thats added to a cell? Surely I cannot release the button at the end of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - that would destroy the button object wouldn't it? All of the snippets I've found with buttons added to cells so far seem to keep instantiation new `UIButton` objects within `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which has me somewhat confused..

Comment: Show the code of cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Buttons are appearing elsewhere because you're using the same cell identifier for different types of cells. Each type of cell should get it's own identifier.
2. In terms of the button disappearing, I don't know why that's happening as a result of `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, but if you move the button to the front of the other subviews, you won't lose it.
3. You probably want to `autorelease` your UITextField. (Same true with NSString in `titleForHeaderInSection`.)

Anyway, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` becomes something like:

```
#define kTextFieldTag 100
#define kButtonFieldTag 101

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// cellForRowAtIndexPath
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier;
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    // Configure the cell...
    switch( [indexPath section] ) 
    {
        case WORKSHEET_SECTION_CLIENT: 
            cellIdentifier = @"CellClient";

            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil) 
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
            }

            cell.textLabel.text = clientName;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;      
            break;

        case WORKSHEET_SECTION_PERIOD: 
        {
            UIButton *myButton1;

            cellIdentifier = @"CellPeriod";

            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil) 
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

                // Don't need UIButton alloc because method below does it for us..
                myButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                myButton1.tag = kButtonFieldTag;

                CGRect cellFrame = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                int nButtonWidth  = 80;
                int nButtonHeight = 30;
                int nActualCellWidth = cellFrame.size.width - 40;
                int nButtonDeltaX = ( nActualCellWidth      - nButtonWidth  ) / 2;
                int nButtonDeltaY = ( cellFrame.size.height - nButtonHeight ) / 2;
                myButton1.frame = CGRectMake( nButtonDeltaX, nButtonDeltaY, nButtonWidth, nButtonHeight );      

                [myButton1 setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                // PDS: Add delaget for stopwatch clicking..
                [myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClickedStopWatch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  

                [cell.contentView addSubview:myButton1];      
            }
            else
            {
                myButton1 = (UIButton *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:kButtonFieldTag];
            }

            cell.textLabel.text = timeElapsed;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;   
            [[cell contentView] bringSubviewToFront:myButton1];

            break;      
        }

        case 2:
            cellIdentifier = @"Cell2";

            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil) 
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
            }

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Amount $130";
            break;      

        case 3:
        {
            cellIdentifier = @"Cell3";

            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            UITextField *myTextField;            

            if (cell == nil) 
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

                myTextField = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,10,125,25)] autorelease];
                [myTextField setTag:kTextFieldTag];
                myTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
                myTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                myTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
                myTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
                myTextField.textAlignment   = UITextAlignmentLeft;
                myTextField.keyboardType    = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
                myTextField.returnKeyType   = UIReturnKeyDone;
                myTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
                //      myTextField.delegate = self;
                myTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

                [cell addSubview:myTextField];
            }
            else
            {
                myTextField = (UITextField *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:kTextFieldTag];
            }

            // note, theoretically, you could blow away anything that the user typed here
            [myTextField setPlaceholder:@"Type Data Here"];          

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
            cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            break;

        }

        default:
            cellIdentifier = @"CellDummy";

            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil) 
            {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
            }

            cell.textLabel.text = @"Dummy";
            break;

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Personally, I might split this into separate methods, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks again! Awesome! I wondered about that CellIdentifier.. I was going to try and assign it a mix of section and row lastnight but a few distractions came along. As for splitting into seperate methods, I'm 100% behind that too. The only problem is that being a newbie to ObjC I struggled a bit with the syntax of passing parameters into my cellForPeriodRow or whatever I called it. :-) The cellForRowAtIndexPath is way too long indeed. Haha. My MacBook keyboard layout don't help either. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you try to retrieve the cell via `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and if that returns `nil`, you create a `UITableViewCell`. Only in that case do you need to create the button. Otherwise the button is already there.

In terms of when to release, you would generally (a) create the button; (b) add it as a subview of the cell; and (c) if ARC code, you'd then release the button there. Because it's been added as a subview, will still have a retain count of 1, and thus won't be dealloc'ed until the cell itself is released (which you never have to worry about ... iOS does that for you).

Thus your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would be something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIButton *button;
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
        [button setTag:kButtonTag]; // if you need to do any reconfiguring of the button, it may be useful to set a tag
        // do additional button configuration
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:button];
        [button release]; // only needed if non-ARC
    }
    else
    {
        // if you need to reconfigure the button, you can grab it from the dequeued cell
        // obviously if you don't need to reconfigure it, you don't need to retrieve it again
        button = (UIButton*)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:kButtonTag];
    }

    // complete the configuration of the cell

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. Great solution to my problem an I think you've also helped me better understand the reference counting process.. I was foolishly thinking that release was the same as dealloc. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't get my head around what my problem is.. Here's a link to some example code: http://www.mediafire.com/?o601abdhaothxs5 If you scroll the screen up for a couple of seconds and then release it, 2 OK buttons will appear.. The first (correct) one will also disappear once after it has been displayed too.. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally after adding the `UIButton` to `UITableViewCell` you can release that. Because after that button will be present with your cell.

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't get my head around what my problem is.. Here's a link to some example code: http://www.mediafire.com/?o601abdhaothxs5 If you scroll the screen up for a couple of seconds and then release it, 2 OK buttons will appear.. The first (correct) one will also disappear once after it has been displayed too.. Any ideas please?